# Woocommerce price label

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a plugin that can set a label after the price. For example, a website selling the game gold. The default price is 0.12 USD, but it is K gold. Buyers always are buying at 200k or more. 0.12 is the unit price. So I'd like to set a label of "K Gold" after the price.

I tried to find plugins at ThemeForest and the official plugins site. All are price options or prices calculated like meter, foot, sq yard, kg, etc. What I need is just a label to let buyers know the price.

[price label at category page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj4KJ.png)

[price label at product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LP6G.png)

[price label label at cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlVhG.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply install this plugin, hopefully, it will fulfill your requirement

https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-before-after-text-products-price-in-woo/

Comment: thank you for your quick reply.  Let me try, I am using the newest version of WordPress. Hope it will be compatible.

Comment: Yes it will be work with newest version too

Comment: This plugin is cool. It works with the newest version. If it can be added to the shopping cart page, it will be perfect.